# Get first message sent to the Bot when using Chain

Tags: c#, botframework

In controller
 `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)`
I execute 
 `await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, ()=> MakeJsonRootDialog());`
Then in implementation how I get first message sent to BOT?
Object completed contains only fields asked during the conversation:

```
public static IDialog<JObject> MakeJsonRootDialog(string strDirPath)
    {
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(preChatInquery.BuildJsonForm))
            .Do(async (context, order) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var completed = await order;

                    await context.PostAsync("Processed your order!");
                }
                catch (FormCanceledException<JObject> e)
                {
                    string reply;
                    if (e.InnerException == null)
                    {
                        reply = $"You quit on {e.Last}--maybe you can finish next time!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reply = "Sorry, I've had a short circuit.  Please try again.";
                    }
                    await context.PostAsync(reply);
                }
            });
```

`

Comment: Any reason you are using Chain and not standard dialogs?

Comment: I used https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot with example for using JSON dialog

Comment: Yes.. but that's is for using FormFlow. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes I want stay with that example - just please help to get first message, which is not stored

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you need to do when using Chain is to Post the message to the chain, using the PostToChain() method.

Here is an example from the [EchoChainDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/EchoBot/EchoChainDialog.cs) sample.

```
public static readonly IDialog<string> dialog = Chain.PostToChain()
            .Select(msg => msg.Text)
```

Comment: Sorry did not get your answer:  How  var completed = await order; will contain first message sent?

Comment: What? instead of doing Chain.From... you need to start with Chain.PostToChain()

Comment: what will be code? 
` public static IDialog<JObject> MakeJsonRootDialog(string strDirPath)
    {   IDialog<string> dialog = Chain.PostToChain()
            .Select(msg => msg.Text);
        return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(preChatInquery.BuildJsonForm))
            .Do(async (context, order) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var completed = await order;

                    await context.PostAsync("Processed your order!");
                } `

Comment: You need to chain the PostToChain with the From, etc.. Using and understanding the use of Chain is an advanced topic, that's why I was asking why you are using it. I would recommend using standards dialog, instead of chain. You can still use FormFlow

Comment: Sorry did not understand your answer. I want that you will show using code snippet how in https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AnnotatedSandwichBot store first message sent to the bot